# Displaying one element at a time

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, javafx

I have a javafx application that signs the files that are uploaded by the user. And it displays the names of these files respectively.

The problem is, to display files on screen, it waits for all files to be signed. After all files signed, suddenly it displays all of the files.

Following gif shows the current status:

[Displayed Files GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjVhN.gif)

But I want to display them in a different way. So, every file should wait previous file to be displayed, before starting their signing process. It is like displaying one element at a time(But not using setInterval or setTimeout). In other words, I want to let Java and Javascript communicate with each other.

I'm using a for loop in the java side. In this for loop I'm calling the javascript function to display the file name in a div.

Java code:

```java
List<String> files = new ArrayList<String>();

for ( Iterator<File> iterator = fWrapper.getFiles().iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
    File unsignedFile = iterator.next();
    String targetFileStr = targetPath + "/" + unsignedFile.getName();
    File signedFile = signer.signUDF(unsignedFile);
    files.add(targetFileStr);

    signedFile.renameTo(new File(targetFileStr));

    Browser.webEngine.executeScript("signedSuccessfully('" + unsignedFile.getName() + " is signed.')"
}
```

And the Javascript code:

```js
 function signedSuccessfully(msg) {
     $("#statusText").append('<br><span style="color:green"> - ' + msg + '</span>');
 }
```

Are there anyone who can give me some advices about how can I do it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm guessing that the code you posted is executed on the FX Application Thread. Execute the loop in a background thread and wrap the call to `executeScript(...)` in `Platform.runLater(...)`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment James, actually I'm an avaricious person in javafx. I guess I'm not working with threads and I guess my code is not executed on the FX Application Thread. Can you be more descriptive about it please? Or do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the signing in a background thread and update the UI each time on the FX Application Thread using [`Platform.runLater(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-)

Since you're collecting the file names in a list, I assume you need that when the process is complete. You can use a `Task` for this and use the `onSucceeded` handler to execute code once the task is complete.

```
Task<List<String>> signingTask = new Task<List<String>>() {
    @Override
    public List<String> call() throws Exception {
        List<String> files = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (File unsignedFile : fWrapper.getFiles()) {
            String targetFileStr = targetPath + "/" + unsignedFile.getName();
            File signedFile = signer.signUDF(unsignedFile);
            files.add(targetFileStr);

            signedFile.renameTo(new File(targetFileStr));

            Platform.runLater(() -> Browser.webEngine.executeScript("signedSuccessfully('" + unsignedFile.getName() + " is signed.')"));
        }
        return files ;
    }
};

signingTask.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
    // this is executed on the FX Application Thread when the task completes successfully
    List<String> signedFiles = signingTask.getValue();
    // do something with signedFiles...
});

signingTask.setOnFailed(e -> {
    Throwable exception = signingTask.getException();
    // this is executed on the FX Application Thread if the task throws an exception
    // inform user something went wrong, etc...
});

Thread t = new Thread(signingTask);
t.start();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer James, but I'm getting "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-10" with this. I have tried many things to solve it but I could not achieve it. Do you have any ideas to fix this issue ? Thanks.

Comment: Which line is throwing that exception?

Comment: I solved it. This exception was occurred from another line. It was not about your code. Thank you for your time.